# Passing a variable in an after_update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, rails-models

I have an `UserProfile` model:

```rb
class UserProfile < ApplicationRecord
  after_update :check_changes

  def check_changes
    AuditRecord.create(account_id: self.id, fields: self.saved_changes , account_type: 'UserProfile', admin_id: 3) if self.saved_changes?
  end
```

| id | user_id | name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | john | doe |
| 2 | 2 | foo | bar |

and `AuditRecord` model:

| id | account_type | account_id | field | admin_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UserProfile | 1 | {} | 3 |
| 2 | UserProfile | 2 | {} | 3 |

This `AuditRecord` saves all of the updates of the profiles, but could be updated by different admins.

How can I send to `check_changes` function the admin_id? Because right now always is going to be 3.

Comment: `after_update` is called automatically. You can't pass some variables there dynamically

Answer (score 0):

1. If I understand correctly, you just want to pass an admin_id to AuditRecord, which means you need another model `Admin`, which is related to `AuditRecord` in some way.
2. Start by generating `Admin` model, set up the appropriate active record association and references.
   [Rails docs for this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)
3. You should be able to access associations now, with something like `admin.auditrecords` depending upon how you set up the associations.

Comment: Sorry about the missunderstood, I have alson an `Admin` model and a `User` model, the problem is that I have a function that updated the `UserProfile`, but every admin can updated the `UserProfile`, but I don't know ho to pass the admin_id in the check_changes function in `UserProfile` model

Comment: In that case, check the [Association Extensions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions) and [Association Callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks). That should help. _According to the articles, you can define custom methods with parameters for associations_

Answer (score 0):

`after_update` is called automatically. You can't pass some variables there dynamically

But you can evenly distribute tasks between admins

```rb
class AuditRecord < ApplicationRecord
  class << self
    def most_free_admin_id
      select(:admin_id).
        group(:admin_id).
        order('COUNT (admin_id)').
        first.
        admin_id
    end
  end
end
```

`AuditRecord.most_free_admin_id` will generate SQL like this

```sql
SELECT admin_id
FROM audit_records
GROUP BY admin_id
ORDER BY COUNT (admin_id)
LIMIT 1;
```

It will return id of the admin who has the least audit records

Also it's better to create such records not after update, but after commit when record is 100% saved in DB. For this purpose `after_update_commit` is better

Also in Ruby we use `self.` only in situations where it is impossible without it

Finally you can apply it in the model

```rb
class UserProfile < ApplicationRecord
  after_update_commit :check_changes

  private

  def check_changes
    AuditRecord.create(
      account_id: id,
      fields: saved_changes,
      account_type: 'UserProfile',
      admin_id: AuditRecord.most_free_admin_id
    )
  end
end
```